# How to find out newest set of (25 or 50)  questions with no answers

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

As on date there is 420+  questions with no-answers and I am unable to find  a way to see answers with no questions for the past one month or newest set of 25 or 50 questions with no answers.

Is there a way for that?

Regards,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for questions with no answers, use `answers:0` - https://askubuntu.com/search?q=answers%3A0. You can then sort them - [by newest](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0), for example.

A full list of search options can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/search