# newest question tab

Tags: feature-request

I am finding it difficult to find the latest new questions that have been asked.

The Active tab shows the latest updates to questions, so older questions are pushed back up to the top.  I think the active tab is useful, but can we have a newest one too?

I would like to be an active member of this stack and try to help contribute to questions as they come in.

I have looked at this question:
[How to find out newest set of (25 or 50)  questions with no answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1058/how-to-find-out-newest-set-of-25-or-50-questions-with-no-answers)

which suggests entering the URL manually (or via a bookmark).
This could help me individually, but I suspect there may be others who would like to view the most recently asked questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest to show them all or
- https://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest to show unanswered only.